# What does 'are you caught up to the show' mean?

Tags: meaning

I was texting with someone and we were talking about Game of Thrones. I said I just finished watching it and she asked "Are you caught up to the show?" I am not native speaker so I couldn't figure out what she meant. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

She most likely meant

> "**Have** you caught up **with** the show?"

Which is asking if you have finished watching all the episodes up to date.

The use of "caught up" [(See def B2)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-up) means:

> Catch up: to learn or discuss the latest news.

Comment: That would certainly be the idiomatic form. "Are you caught up to the show" is not a form of expression which is normally used in Britain.

Comment: @WS2: But to be fair, this was a casual conversation between friends, and via text messaging (which also lowers the average grammatical standard for communication).

Comment: @Flater Sadly, yes it does!

Answer (score 1):

**"Are you caught up to the show?"** is another way of saying **"Have you watched the most recent episode?"** or **"Have you seen all the previous episodes?"**.

For instance, if I were going to talk to someone about the most recent episode, first I'd ask them if they were **"caught up"**, as in, have they **caught up** to where the show is now.

Comment: Care to cite some sources?

Comment: @Kris Source: Native speaker of American English. If it makes you feel better, I asked someone if they were caught up on GoT just an hour before seeing this question, and there was zero confusion.

Comment: @Sinjai Even natives get it wrong sometimes... your last sentence is a comment, by the way.

Comment: @marcellothearcane You're right, but the only source I have is myself. Yes, it's a comment, but I don't have comment privileges. <s>No one else mentioned it to the OP and it can avoid questions like this in the future.</s> I didn't notice it's already mentioned in the moderation flag. Whether OP will see it if I missed it is arguable, but I'll remove it from my post regardless.

Comment: '*it can avoid questions like this in the future.*' don't you believe it! :D